# Автодополнение кода SQL в консоле при подключении к mysql серверу?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как настроить автодополнение кода SQL в консоле при подключении к mysql серверу?
И сразу приведу свой пример что нашел. [mycli](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli)

С плюсов это автодополнение и подсветка синтаксиса. Эще есть pgcli для Postgres.

Установка: В Ubuntu 16.04+ з официального репозитория:

```
$ sudo apt install mycli
```

После установки виполните эту команду чтобы увидеть пример подключения в серверу mysql

```
$ mycli --help

Usage: mycli [OPTIONS] [DATABASE]

  A MySQL terminal client with auto-completion and syntax highlighting.
1
  Examples:
    - mycli my_database
    - mycli -u my_user -h my_host.com my_database
    - mycli mysql://my_user@my_host.com:3306/my_database
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ нашел здесь https://askubuntu.com/questions/353460/how-to-use-sql-in-terminal

Comment: Размещённое сообщение не является вопросом. И больше всего похоже на (само?) рекламу.

Comment: Спасибо! Как-то это раньше мимо меня прошло...